# Render only specific chart using dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

How can I render only specific chart not all using dc.js.

renderAll() function accepts group. However, what is group in this context is not clear. Following doesnt work,

```
var priceChart = dc.rowChart("#price-chart");
dc.renderAll(priceChart)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to write instead is :

```
var priceChart = dc.rowChart("#price-chart","mygroup");
dc.renderAll("mygroup");
```

Answer (score 3):

`PriceChart.render()` works now as well.

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanna render all charts in the same group (for example, under "mygroup" you have rowChart, barChart... then when you do renderAll("mygroup") it will render everything under the same group.

```
var priceChart = dc.rowChart("#price-chart","mygroup");
dc.renderAll("mygroup");
```

In some cases you dont want to do it, you should use

```
priceChart.render();
```

instead of

```
dc.renderAll("mygroup");
```